# Proof that $f_{n} = \chi_{\Omega_{n}}f \to f$ in $L^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an unbounded measurable function and let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^{2}d\mu(x) < +\infty$$
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\Omega_{n} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x)| \le n\}$ and $\chi_{\Omega_{n}}$ its characteristic function, i.e. $\chi_{\Omega_{n}}(x) = 1 $ if $x \in \Omega_{n}$ and zero otherwise. I'm trying to prove that the sequence of functions $f_{n} := \chi_{\Omega_{n}}f$ is Cauchy and converges in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mu)$ to $f$. My work so far is as follows:
$$||f_{n}-f_{m}||^{2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{\Omega_{n}}f-\chi_{\Omega_{m}}f|^{2}d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\chi_{\Omega_{n}}-\chi_{\Omega_{m}}|^{2}|f|^{2}d\mu$$
Now, assuming $m \le n$, we notice that $\Omega_{m}\subseteq \Omega_{n}$, so that $|\chi_{\Omega_{n}}-\chi_{\Omega_{m}}| = \chi_{\Omega_{n}}-\chi_{\Omega_{m}} = \chi_{\Omega_{n}\setminus \Omega_{m}}$. Hence,
$$||f_{n}-f_{m}||^{2} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{\Omega_{n}\setminus\Omega_{m}}|f|^{2}d\mu = \int_{\Omega_{n}\setminus\Omega_{m}}|f|^{2}d\mu$$
But I'm stuck here. How can I prove this is Cauchy?

Comment: If $m<n$, $f_n-f_m=f\mathbb{1}_{\{m<f\leq n\}}$. Cauchy-Schwartz along with  Markov-Chebishev's inequalities may come handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the dominated convergence theorem extended to $L^2$.
Naturally, $|f_n(x)|^2 \le |f(x)|^2$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so from the dominated convergence theorem,
$$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int |f-f_n|^2d\mu = 0.$$

For more details for how to move from the $L^1$ version to any $L^p$ version of the theorem you can check
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem
in the Dominated convergence in Lp-spaces section.

Comment: Very elegant approach.  I think the extension of the DCT to $L^{p}$ goes as follows. Because $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise, we can define $h_{n} = |f_{n}-f|$, so that $h_{n} \to 0$ pointwise and, consequently, $\varphi_{n} := h_{n}^{2} = |f_{n}-f|^{2} \to 0$ pointwise as well. Moreover, $\varphi_{n}$ is bounded by $\varphi_{n} \le |f_{n}|+|f|$, so we can apply the DCT to $\varphi_{n}$.

Comment: @MathMath Almost. Your $\phi_n$ is not bounded by $|f_n|+|f|$ because of the square on the right side. But one can find a similar bound in terms of $|f_n|^2$ and $|f|^2$.

Comment: @MaoWao ops, you're right. Actually $\varphi_{n} \le 2(|f_{n}|^{2}+|f|^{2})$!